# Overwrite data dropdown values in search form (multipleSearch)

Tags: jqgrid

I'm having a colModel entry like this:

```
{name:'status', index:'status', sorttype:"text", xmlmap:"STATUS", width:"90", stype: 'select', searchoptions:{sopt: ['eq','ne'], value:':all;Hold:Hold;4-Eye-Check:4-Eye-Check;Approved:Approved;Rejected:Rejected;Closed:Closed'}},
```

thats working fine as long as it's used in the FilterToolBar, but if I open the NavGridSearch Im running into troubles. The entry "all" is not working anymore. The query in the FilterToolBar seems to ignore my empty  but the NavGridSearch doesn't.

Is there any wildcard sign which could be used instead of an empty String, which delivers all entries regardless if I search for all status entries in the FilterToolBar or the NavGridSearch?

I use the newest OpenSource jQGrid Lib(4.3.2)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am trying to understand the use case for a criteria of 'all'. It seems the purpose of 'all' is that you want the grid to ignore this search criteria and return all rows regardless of this value? If that is the case, why would the user even want to select this search criteria - they can just remove it and the same effect will be achieved. Or am I missing something?

---

**Update**

The grid uses function `createEl : function(eltype,options,vl,autowidth, ajaxso)` to create the select for the search form. Unfortunately this select always adds the `all` criteria to the list, even though it has a search value of `""` which will not match any rows. One workaround is to modify the grid to skip select options that have an empty value. Using the source file `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` you can add the following code to skip the `all` option:

```
else if (sv.length > 1 && sv[0].length === 0) continue;
```

Here it is within the context of `createEl`:

```
                if(typeof options.value === 'string') {
                    so = options.value.split(delim);
                    for(i=0; i<so.length;i++){
                        sv = so[i].split(sep);
                        if(sv.length > 2 ) {
                            sv[1] = $.map(sv,function(n,ii){if(ii>0) { return n;} }).join(sep);
                        } else if (sv.length > 1 && sv[0].length === 0) continue; // <-- Change this line
                        ov = document.createElement("option");
                        ov.setAttribute("role","option");
                        ov.value = sv[0]; ov.innerHTML = sv[1];
                        elem.appendChild(ov);
                        if (!msl &&  ($.trim(sv[0]) == $.trim(vl) || $.trim(sv[1]) == $.trim(vl))) { ov.selected ="selected"; }
                        if (msl && ($.inArray($.trim(sv[1]), ovm)>-1 || $.inArray($.trim(sv[0]), ovm)>-1)) {ov.selected ="selected";}
                    }
```

If you  need a minified version, update the "src" version of jqGrid and then run it through the Google Closure Compiler.

I am not sure this is a general purpose change, which is why I am calling it a workaround for right now. Longer term a better solution needs to be found so jqGrid can be patched... I'll try to find some more time later to revisit this issue.

Does that help?

Comment: Hi Justin
Thanks a lot for your answer.
The problem is, if I don't specify an <option> all, the filter toolbar shows the value "Hold" as selected when the user comes to the page or makes a refresh, even though "Hold" isn't selected.

Here is a similar example http://ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/EditingTest.htm it has the same problem as my grid. 

Do you have any ideas? 
thx

Comment: Understood. But that example is for a filter toolbar. Do you really need the "Any" on the popup filter dialog? Because on that screen if you do not need a filter criteria then you can just elect not to add a filter for that column at all. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Hi Justin, in fact exactly this column is the reason why I have to use the popup search. The user must have the possibilty to filter for more than just one status at a time. Unfortunately I couldn't find a solution to implement a "multiple dropdown filter" behavior for the filter toolbar, or is there one? Very appreciate your help!

Comment: I'm still back to why what jqGrid is doing right now is not good enough. What do you mean by `The entry "all" is not working anymore`? Maybe a specific example would help.

Comment: Hi Justin, I've created a reduced version of my grid. Please see here: http://www.dontworry.ch/files/jqgrid.html

Comment: Hi Justin
Thanks a lot for this great solution, it's exactly what I was looking for! Warm regards to Baltimore!

Comment: You're welcome! Please consider accepting this answer too if it works out for you... :)